# National Insurance Number Validation

Tags: beginner, php

I'm a beginner to PHP and I've written a function that validates a U.K National Insurance Number. The function works by checking whether the given number against the format below;

> The National Insurance Number (`$NINO`) is made up of 3 components in the
>   format AAnnnnnnA. The 3 components are the prefix, numeric body and
>   suffix.
>
> **Prefix**
>
> The first two alpha characters, validated as follows:
>
> • The prefix must not be BG, GB, NK, KN, TN, NT or ZZ
>
> • The prefix must not contain D F I Q U or V
>
> • The second character of the NINo prefix must not be O
>
> **Numeric body**
>
> The 8 numeric characters of the NINO, validated as follows:
>
> • Must be numeric in the range 000000 – 999999
>
> **Suffix**
>
> The final alpha character; validated as follows:
>
> • Must be in the range A – D

```
<?php

function validateNI($NINO) {
    $NILength = strlen($NINO);

    if (!($NILength < 10 | $NILength > 10)) {
        $NIParts = str_split($NINO, 2);

        if(!(preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(BG|GB|NK|TN|NT|ZZ|D|F|I|Q|U|V)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $NIParts[0]))) {

            $NIPartsSplit = str_split($NIParts[0]);

            if(preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(O)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $NIPartsSplit[1])) {
                echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
            } else {
                $NIPartsNum = $NIParts[1].$NIParts[2].$NIParts[3];

                if (is_numeric($NIPartsNum)) {

                    if(preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(A|B|C|D)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $NIParts[4])) {
                        echo "Valid National Insurance Number.";
                    } else {
                        echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
                }
            }

        } else {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }
}

validateNI("AA1220091A");

?>
```

I'm looking for advice on how I can reduce the overall lines of code (including the use of regex) as well as increasing the efficiency and simplicity of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue I see is it's very hard to read. You have too many levels (nesting) of `If/Else`, but also too much code in them which makes it hard to see where everything starts and ends etc. Also you have duplicated messages.

You code can either be condensed into less checks to return the same error message, or even just split out the issues into separate blocks, reverse your logic, and return early.

A very basic example of this idea (not necessarily the best approach for your code), instead of your code:

```
if (!($NILength < 10 | $NILength > 10)) {
    // 23 lines of code including 4 IFs 4 more levels deep and 3 elses
} else {
    echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
}
```

Instead do this:

```
if ($NILength < 10 || $NILength > 10) {
    echo "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    return;
}
```

So instead of `if thing is ok do the thing...else...` you just do `if thing is NOT ok return` then there's no need to even have an else because if it didn't return then it was a false statement (no error) and the code can move along to the next check.

Additionally, instead of echoing in this function, most times you are better off returning a value (even a string error message). The problem with echoing from such a function is it makes it hard to *re-use* in another scenario where it doesn't want to echo something.

Your first IF is written in an overly complicated way.

```
if (!($NILength < 10 | $NILength > 10)) {
```

> If length is not less than 10
>   AND
>   If length is not greater than 10

This is simply:

> If length is 10

```
if ($NILength === 10) {
```

Also as you only use this var once, it's arguably superfluous you can just check the passed in var with `strlen()`.

---

**NOTE:** I don't declare any of this code to be tested or working. This is more about theory than actual working code.

**Basic Refactor:**

This is a basic refactor your function to return early incorporating above points (also some PSR standard added with proper spaces etc). This is a bit cleaner and you can see the "moving parts" more clearly - that is each potential reason why the data is invalid or valid.

```
function validateNI($niNo)
{
    if (empty($niNo)) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    if (strlen($niNo) !== 10) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    $niParts = str_split($niNo, 2);

    if ((preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(BG|GB|NK|TN|NT|ZZ|D|F|I|Q|U|V)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niParts[0]))) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    $niPartsSplit = str_split($niParts[0]);

    if (preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(O)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niPartsSplit[1])) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    $niPartsNum = $niParts[1] . $niParts[2] . $niParts[3];

    if (!is_numeric($niPartsNum)) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

     if (!preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(A|B|C|D)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niParts[4])) {
         return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
     }

     return "Valid National Insurance Number.";
}
```

I've added an `empty()` check on the passed in var to avoid "undefined var" warning.

I think the function above is tidy and clear.

Some people set a variable in each check and return that at the end, as well as other approaches. However, why let PHP run through a load of additional checks when something has already determined there's a problem? Unless you stack up different errors, but you do not here.
[Return Early](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

You can go another step and as you only have one error message setting a var is a bit tidier too (and means easier to change that shared message in one place later):

```
function validateNI($niNo)
{
    $errorMessage = 'Invalid National Insurance Number';

    if (empty($niNo)) {
        return $errorMessage;
    }

    if (strlen($niNo) !== 10) {
        return $errorMessage;
    }

    // ETC

   return "Valid National Insurance Number.";
}
```

You could probs tidy some of the actual code up (beyond structure) and even pair some of the errors together, such as:

```
function validateNI($niNo)
{
    if (empty($niNo) || strlen($niNo) !== 10) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    $niParts = str_split($niNo, 2);
    $niPartsSplit = str_split($niParts[0]);
    $niPartsNum = $niParts[1] . $niParts[2] . $niParts[3];

    if (
        preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(BG|GB|NK|TN|NT|ZZ|D|F|I|Q|U|V)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niParts[0]) 
        || preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(O)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niPartsSplit[1]) 
        || !is_numeric($niPartsNum)
        ||!preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(A|B|C|D)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niParts[4])
    ) {
        return "Invalid National Insurance Number.";
    }

    return "Valid National Insurance Number.";
}
```

Even though that is a shorter function, I think it's harder to read as there's a lot of regex bunched together. This is subjective though and where a dev's personal style comes in to play (or more so a team's unified decision).

---

**Class:**

Going one step further, all of this would be in a class as this is the modern way:

```
class ValidateNationalInsuranceNumber
{
    /**
     * @param string $niNo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function validateNi($niNo)
    {
        $errorMessage = 'Invalid National Insurance Number.';

        if (!$this->isLengthValid($niNo)) {
            return $errorMessage;
        };

        $niParts = str_split($niNo, 2);

        if (
            !$this->isPrefixValid($niParts[0])
            || !$this->isBodyValid($niParts)
            || !$this->isSuffixValid($niParts[4])
        ) {
            return $errorMessage;
        }

        return 'Valid National Insurance Number.';
    }

    /**
     * @param string $niNo
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isLengthValid($niNo)
    {
        if (empty($niNo) || strlen($niNo) !== 10) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $prefix
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isPrefixValid($prefix)
    {
        $niPartsSplit = str_split($prefix);

        if (
            preg_match(
                "/[^!@#$%^&*]*(BG|GB|NK|TN|NT|ZZ|D|F|I|Q|U|V)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i",
                $prefix
            )
            || preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(O)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $niPartsSplit[1])
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $niParts
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isBodyValid(array $niParts)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($niParts[1] . $niParts[2] . $niParts[3])) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $suffix
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isSuffixValid($suffix)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(A|B|C|D)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $suffix)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am happy for you, that you are asking for help with refactoring this scary function.
First of all, you must not write more than 2 indentations with `if` statements, if you want to be a great developer.

Secondly, when you write a program, keep in your mind that every method or function must do one simple task.

Well, what is the responsibility of your function?

1. check insurance number Length.
2. check prefix.
3. check the second string of prefix.
4. check suffix.
5. check the numeric body number.

Perfect, why must we create a class instead of keeping your method?

There is one principle, it is KISS(Keep it simple stupid),
the main idea behind this principle is to keep your methods or classes as simple and stupid as possible.

For that, we should create new methods for our responsibilities above. For example to check the first responsibility which is "check insurance number length" we will create a method called `isNotValidInsuranceNumberLength` to do that for us etc..

Since we have many methods, we should encapsulate all of them within a class, that will be its responsibility to take care of the national insurance number validation.

And this touches on the SRP(single responsibility principle) because we must ensure that our class will have one and only one reason to change(validation of the national insurance number).

I was changing the imbricated `if` statements by small methods that describe what they do exactly by its name.

> I advise you, that when you write code think like you are writing a
>   story.
>
> another advice: read Uncle Bob clean code's book.

my refactorization is below :

```
<?php

class  NationalInsuranceNumberValidator
{
    $insuranceNumber = null;

    public function __construct($insuranceNumber)
    {
        $this->insuranceNumber = $insuranceNumber;
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        if($this->isNotValidInsuranceNumberLength())
        {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number. isNotValidInsurenceNumberLength";
        }
        elseif($this->prefixIsNotValid())
        {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number. prefixIsNotValid";
        }
        elseif($this->secondPartOfPefixIsNotValid())
        {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number. secondPartOfPefixIsNotValid";
        }
        elseif($this->suffixIsNotValid())
        {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number. suffixIsNotValid";
        }
        elseif($this->isNotNumericBody())
        {
            echo "Invalid National Insurance Number. isNotValidNumericBody";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Valid National Insurance Number.";
        }
    }

    private function isNotValidInsuranceNumberLength()
    {
        $insuranceNumberLength = strlen($this->insuranceNumber);

        return $insuranceNumberLength < 10 || $insuranceNumberLength > 10;
    }

    private function prefixIsNotValid()
    {
        return preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(BG|GB|NK|TN|NT|ZZ|D|F|I|Q|U|V)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $this->getPrefix()) == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    private function secondPartOfPefixIsNotValid()
    {
        $prefix = $this->getPrefix();

        return preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(O)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $prefix[1]) == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    private function suffixIsNotValid()
    {
        return preg_match("/[^!@#$%^&*]*(A|B|C|D)[^!@#$%^&*]*/i", $this->getSuffix()) == 1 ? false : true;
    }

    private function isNotNumericBody()
    {
        return !is_numeric($this->getNumericBody());
    }

    private function getPrefix()
    {
        return substr($this->insuranceNumber, 0, 2);
    }

    private function getNumericBody()
    {
        return substr($this->insuranceNumber, 2, 7);
    }

    private function getSuffix()
    {
        return substr($this->insuranceNumber, 9, 1);
    }
}


$nationalInsuranceNumber = new NationalInsuranceNumberValidator('AA1220091C');

$nationalInsuranceNumber->validate();
```